# SQL Trim login to initials

Tags: sql, postgresql, regexp-replace

Truncate login to initials

Hi!

To calculate statistics, which initials are more common in logins, I need to leave only initials (without a number at the end, if it is present)
I have a data column with a login like:

| login |
| --- |
| MiaevaMO |
| DevskaAM2 |
| PenichiMN |
| PopovinAV36 |
| GokovDN |

Tried through

```
regexp_replace(login, '[a-z]','')
```

in result:

| login | с_login |
| --- | --- |
| MiaevaMO | MMO |
| DevskaAM2 | DAM2 |
| PenichiMN | PMN |
| PopovinAV36 | PAV36 |
| GokovDN | GDN |

but this is not quite what I need.
should get:

| login | с_login |
| --- | --- |
| MiaevaMO | MO |
| DevskaAM2 | AM |
| PenichiMN | MN |
| PopovinAV36 | AV |
| GokovDN | DN |

What's I do wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: What happens to your statistics when both user "DevskaAM2" and user "DevskaAM1" are active? And/Or howabout user "JacksonAM". You can generally assume that login values are unique, but **not** sub strings of them.

Comment: @Belayer In my system, these two logins will be different but in my final request they are summed up (because the same initials 'AM'). The same is rendered 'JacksonAM'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace()` to get the upper case letters at the end of the string:

```
select regexp_replace(login, '^.*[^A-Z*]([A-Z]+)[0-9]*$', '\1')
from (values ('MiaevaMO'), ('DevskaAM2')) v(login)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f30a7a0a9f3983e7523314f33a1c2b4b) is a db<>fiddle.